# Number format exception when deploying Quarkus application using Kubernetes Extention

Tags: java, kubernetes, quarkus

I am trying to deploy Quarkus application using Kubernetes Extension.

But when the application runs, it shows the following error.

```
(main) Error running Quarkus application:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus 
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "tcp://10.96.112.33:8101"
With 10.96.112.33:8101 is the IP Address of ClusterIp on Kubernetes
```

Please help me!
Thanks

[Quarkus Kubernetes Extention Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgKdR.jpg)

Comment: Where did you enter this input string? Please check properties and their types: https://quarkus.io/guides/kubernetes#configuration-options

Comment: Yes, I do. 
Here are all things in my config
quarkus.kubernetes.host=172.16.31.247
quarkus.kubernetes. service-account=default
quarkus.kubernetes-config.enabled=true
quarkus.kubernetes-config.config-maps=api-prefix
quarkus.kubernetes-cLient.namespace=mano-quarkus
quarkus.http.port=8101
quarkus.kubernetes. service-type=NodePort
quarkus.container-image.name=vmanager
quarkus.container-image.tag=1.0
quarkus. kubernetes . depLoyment-target=kubernetes
quarkus.jib.base-jvm-image=docker-registry:5000/gcr.io/distroless/java:11

Comment: @Manh.NT any solution to this?